# Android asks which app to use to scan barcodes

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm using zxing in my app to scan barcodes, and I've got it scanning just fine.  We have several apps that do scanning, however (different branded apps for each customer), and I see that when I start the Activity to scan a barcode, the phone asks which app I want to use.  There are two problems with that.  First, I want each app to always use ITSELF as the scanning app when the scan button is clicked, and second, I don't want another app that I didn't write trying to use my app to scan barcodes.

How do I enforce the first item and prevent the second?  I tried to find something to put into the manifest, maybe, but didn't come up with anything.

EDIT - here's the manifest (with some information obscured) (the app presents a LoginActivity, then the screen with the scan button (MainActivity), then sends the barcode to a website which returns more information, displayed in the ResultActivity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MyCompany.MyApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyCompany.MyApp.LoginActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyCompany.MyApp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyCompany.MyApp.HelpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyCompany.MyApp.ResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are actually the same issue...Do you call zxing through an intent to use its scanner? If so, your own apps are probably listening to the same intent, which causes them to react when you start a scan.

You can check your manifest for activities that have an intent filter of scanning.

-----------Update---------

That CaptureActivity has the intent filter for Scan. That's the cause. If you have embedded zxing's code into your app instead of calling their app, you can remove this intent filter.

Comment: @jfren484 see my update. Try removing the intent filter and make sure you call the CaptureActivity in you app through a Explicit Intent.

Comment: When I do that it fires up the scanner activity just fine, but after scanning in a code the screen shows the scanned image, the text that was decoded, and then three buttons (something like share, search the web, and I forget the third).  It doesn't fire my onActivityResult method.  So I put back in the intent filters, but set the package explicitly.  It now does not ask which app I want to have handle the scan, but other apps can still use mine (looks like android ignores the exported=false attribute).  Still not perfect, but probably good enough for now.

Comment: @jfren484 So StartActivityForResult does not fire onActivityResult? That's weird. It should work no matter how the intent is defined.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Maybe I'm creating the intent wrong.  This is how I tried creating it (sorry, can't get it to format nicely):
`Intent scanActivity = new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
scanActivity.setPackage("com.MyCompany.MyApp");
startActivityForResult(scanActivity, 0);`

Comment: @jfren484, your code looks correct to me. Just to confirm I understand you correctly, the issue is that when intent filter for CaptureActivity is removed from manifest, the CaptureActivity doesn't call back onActivityResult ? And while the intent filter is present, the CaptureActivity works fine. Is it?

Comment: Yes, when I remove the intent filter and create the intent using `new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class)`, instead of populating my text box with the scanned data, I get the screen in [this screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/87782593@N04/8033009528/in/photostream)

Comment: When I have a chance (this afternoon or Monday, maybe), I'll create a sample app that only has the scanning piece in it and upload the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is to set the Action on the Intent

Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
intent.setAction(com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Scan.ACTION);          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

This worked for me.